# node.js emitter.on to python

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm working on an amazon Alexa skill to call the wolfram alpha API and return the results. I found a node.js version to do it, but I'm trying to translate it to python (which I'm more familiar with). Also I really wasn't sure how much code to put, so sorry about the wall.

Original node.js code:

var request = http.get( url, function( response ) {

```
    var xml = '';

    response.on( 'data', function( x ) { xml += x; } );

    response.on( 'end', function() {

        xml = xml.replace( /\n/g, ' ' );

        var pattern = /plaintext>(.*?)<\/plaintext/g;
        var answers = [];

        while ( ( match = pattern.exec( xml )) !== null ) {

            answers.push( match[1] );

        }

        if ( answers[1] === '' ) output( answers[2], context );
        else output( answers[1], context );

    } );

} );
```

My poorly translated python:

```
request = fix_request(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())


def fix_request(response):
    """Takes the response and fixes it. Tries to fix it.
    It would really help if I knew the data type,
    but prints or logs don't work even with the imports."""
    if response != None:
        xml = ''

        xml += response['data'] # I think the left means the same as under was supposed to
        #response.on('data', lambda x: xml += x)


        response.on('end', lambda: 
            xml = xml.re( "/\n/g", " ")

            pattern = re.compile("plaintext>(.*?)<\/plaintext")
            answers = []

            while (match = re.findall(pattern, xml) != None):
                answers.append(match[1])
            if answers[1] === '':
                output(answers[2], context)
            else:
                output(answers[1], context)
```

Comment: I would use http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ over urllib2 any day

Comment: @Brandon I would use anything else too, but I don't know if the aws lambda server can get those. Additionally because it charges based on run time, installing and running every time isn't great.

Comment: We just started a project [bstpy](https://github.com/bespoken/bstpy) to expose a Python lambda as an http service. You may find it useful for testing. You can throw json payloads at it with curl or postman. If you try it with other  [Bespoken Tools](https://github.com/bespoken/bst) you can a have very nice development environment.